# School project GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, interface

I'm currently working on a schoolproject involving a parkinggarage. We currently have a simulator working but for some reason I can't seem to be able to fix the GUI. Note that this is my first Java project ever and that I'm new to programming in general.

[This is how the GUI currently look like, obviously it's not looking like it's supposed to look. My idea was that the buttons are beneath the simulator grid and are alot smaller than they are now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y1F6.jpg)

```
public class SimulatorView extends JFrame {
    private CarParkView carParkView;
    private int numberOfFloors;
    private int numberOfRows;
    private int numberOfPlaces;
    private Car[][][] cars;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JLabel label;
    private Simulator sim;

    public SimulatorView(int numberOfFloors, int numberOfRows, int numberOfPlaces, Simulator sim) {
        this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
        this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        this.numberOfPlaces = numberOfPlaces;
        this.sim = sim;
        cars = new Car[numberOfFloors][numberOfRows][numberOfPlaces];

        carParkView = new CarParkView();

        button1 = new JButton("Run 1 time");
        button2 = new JButton("Run 100 times");
        label = new JLabel("Test bericht");

        event a = new event();
        button1.addActionListener(a);

        event2 b = new event2();
        button2.addActionListener(b);

      //  Dimension d = new Dimension(100,100);
      //  button1.setBounds(20,30,50,30);
      //  button2.setBounds(20,30,50,30);



        //
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Parking Simulator");
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setBounds(10,10,1024,1024);
        //
        Container contentPane = jf.getContentPane();
        //contentPane.add(stepLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(carParkView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(button1,BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add(button2,BorderLayout.WEST);
        //contentPane.add(population, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        updateView();
    }


    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
            sim.singletick();
        }
    }


    public class event2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
            Thread queryThread = new Thread(); {
            sim.hundredtick();
                }
        }
    }


    public void updateView() {
        carParkView.updateView();
    }

    public int getNumberOfFloors() {
        return numberOfFloors;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return numberOfRows;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlaces() {
        return numberOfPlaces;
    }

    public Car getCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        return cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()];
    }

    public boolean setCarAt(Location location, Car car) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return false;
        }
        Car oldCar = getCarAt(location);
        if (oldCar == null) {
            cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = car;
            car.setLocation(location);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Car removeCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        Car car = getCarAt(location);
        if (car == null) {
            return null;
        }
        cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = null;
        car.setLocation(null);
        return car;
    }

    public Location getFirstFreeLocation() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    if (getCarAt(location) == null) {
                        return location;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Car getFirstLeavingCar() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null && car.getMinutesLeft() <= 0 && !car.getIsPaying()) {
                        return car;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void tick() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null) {
                        car.tick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean locationIsValid(Location location) {
        int floor = location.getFloor();
        int row = location.getRow();
        int place = location.getPlace();
        if (floor < 0 || floor >= numberOfFloors || row < 0 || row > numberOfRows || place < 0 || place > numberOfPlaces) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class CarParkView extends JPanel {

        private Dimension size;
        private Image carParkImage;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class CarPark
         */
        public CarParkView() {
            size = new Dimension(0, 0);
        }

        /**
         * Overridden. Tell the GUI manager how big we would like to be.
         */
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 400);
        }

        /**
         * Overriden. The car park view component needs to be redisplayed. Copy the
         * internal image to screen.
         */
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (carParkImage == null) {
                return;
            }

            Dimension currentSize = getSize();
            if (size.equals(currentSize)) {
                g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
            else {
                // Rescale the previous image.
                g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, currentSize.width, currentSize.height, null);
            }
        }

        public void updateView() {
            // Create a new car park image if the size has changed.
            if (!size.equals(getSize())) {
                size = getSize();
                carParkImage = createImage(size.width, size.height);
            }
            Graphics graphics = carParkImage.getGraphics();
            for(int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
                for(int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                    for(int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                        Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                        Car car = getCarAt(location);
                        Color color = car == null ? Color.white : Color.red;
                        drawPlace(graphics, location, color);
                    }
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Paint a place on this car park view in a given color.
         */
        private void drawPlace(Graphics graphics, Location location, Color color) {
            graphics.setColor(color);
            graphics.fillRect(
                    location.getFloor() * 260 + (1 + (int)Math.floor(location.getRow() * 0.5)) * 75 + (location.getRow() % 2) * 20,
                    60 + location.getPlace() * 10,
                    20 - 1,
                    10 - 1); // TODO use dynamic size or constants
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question ;)

Comment: First time using StackOverFLow, I've just added the code.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I want to be able to change the position of the buttons and the size. But they appear huge and over the simulator view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your constraints you want to use `BorderLayout`. But you do not set the `BorderLayout` as layout manager. Do `setLayout(new BorderLayout())` on your content panel.

Comment: I've been searching through that info for hours yet I can't figure out how to fix my current GUI.

Comment: See updated answer. (Update was possible because you posted the sources, before it was not obvious ;-) )

Comment: If the answer now answered your question, you should accept it as answer and optionally also upvote it. (And restrain from the words "school project" or "homework" in questions, as you will really fast get negative votes on your question if it seems that you are searching for someone doing your homework ;-) )

Comment: I've added the BorderLayout, which gives me the error that i'm missing the appropiate method. As the newbie I am, i've no idea what to exactly set in the method

Comment: `contentPane.setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout())` does NOT work? o_O

Comment: The setLayoutManager gives an error (cannot resolve method 'java.awt.BorderLayout;'

Comment: @Vampire "restrain from the words "school project" or "homework" in questions" - I disagree. If it indeed **is** a school project or homework, one should state so. The question should not be of the "please do my work" type anyway. From my experience it is much more frowned upon and quickly downvoted if the question looks like homework but the OP won't say so. I am sure there will be a meta-post on that topic but I did not look for it.

Comment: @lloydd4 please show your code that wont work. I guess you forgot the `new`

Comment: @Fildor hm, possible. I'm just wondering that he quickly got downvotes which are not really valid in my opinion as it is a typical problem and a fine question. I thought they downvoted just because the have seen the word school project.

Comment: @Vampire absolutely possible. Some people are pretty quick with downvotes when it comes to beginners' question that they consider "oh, he could have found that out easily ... ". But they often forget that it is not easy to find something, when you do not know what you have to look for. And sometimes, you'll get downvotes nobody other than the downvoter himself can understand ...

Comment: `Container contentPane = jf.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout());
        //contentPane.add(stepLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(carParkView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(button1,BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add(button2,BorderLayout.WEST);
        //contentPane.add(population, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` this is what i currently have

Comment: ah, my bad, it is `setLayout()`, not `setLayoutManager()`, answer is updated